# How to download all the messages in a Telegram group?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

I am trying to use the below code in a Jupyter NoteBook to download all the messages of a specific Telegram group:

```py
import csv
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession

api_id = 'YOUR_API_ID'
api_hash = 'YOUR_API_HASH'

session = StringSession()

async def print_messages():
    async with TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash) as client:
        with open('messages.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(['Sender ID', 'Text'])

            channel_username = 'channelusername'
            entity = await client.get_entity(channel_username)

            async for message in client.iter_messages(entity, limit=None):
                writer.writerow([message.sender_id, message.text])

task = asyncio.create_task(print_messages())

await task
```

It works without errors, however, it only gives me the first 25 or so messages not all. I also tried changing the limit to `limit=1000` to no avail. Suspecting that the Telegram rate limit is the issue I also tried adding

```
await asyncio.sleep(2)  # sleep for 2 seconds
```

inside the `async for` loop, but it did not help either.

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how to solve it.

**P.S.** I posted the question also [here](https://t.me/Python/1889166) on Telegram.

Comment: Have you tried printing the message ID? Does it reach 1? Are you sure the group you're using is the one you expect to be using?

Comment: @Lonami I am not sure what do you mean. Would you be kind to elaborate with an example? I am 99% sure I am downloading a from the correct group. at least the messages it is downloading are correct.

Comment: I was suggesting you to `print(message.id)`. If it reaches 1 (or close), you've likely reached the end of the group. Note that channels migrated from small group chats don't have the old messages migrated. Those are still fetched from the old chat, but I don't know if this is your case.